# Senna Semantic Role Labellar in Python

Tags: nlp, senna, srl

I want to measure the similarity of the two sentence using Senna Semantic Role Labellar. I have read articles in the internet about it but couldn't implement and use it in python.As I am Learning about Senna SRL, Please suggest me some good resources about Senna SRL from beginning to advance in Python for windows machine.

Consider a sentence **He knows a good boy**
After senna srl it stands **He[A0] knows[v] (a good boy)[A1]**